# Virtual key-press to function-key of a gaming keyboard

Tags: keyboard, autoit, keycode

How to virtually activate special function keys of a "MadCatz Strike 7" keyboard? Sending its key code should have MadCatz7 software act as if registering a physical key press.

Are there key codes for these function keys (or is there a better way)? I am working on an AutoIt script that should let MadCatz software do the rest by activating corresponding special function keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that without telling the MadCatz software directly that the special key was pressed, so that the software would launch the programmed template.

I solved the problem using an AutoIt Script and will post the code when it's done.

Answer (score 2):

Try to figure out the key with this code. Normally your specail function keys have a alternative hotkey as ctrl+alt+F10 or something.

```
Opt('GUICloseOnESC', 0)

Global $tState = DllStructCreate('byte[256]')

GUICreate('MyGUI', 200, 200)
$Label = GUICtrlCreateLabel('', 20, 72, 160, 52, 0x01)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 32, 800, 0, 'Tahoma')
GUISetState()

$Prev = -1

While 1
    Sleep(10)
    If GUIGetMsg() = -3 Then
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
    $Key = 0
    $Ret = DllCall('user32.dll', 'int', 'GetKeyboardState', 'ptr', DllStructGetPtr($tState))
    For $i = 0x08 To 0xFF
        Switch $i
            Case 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0E To 0x0F, 0x16, 0x1A, 0x1C To 0x1F, 0x3A To 0x40, 0x5E, 0x88 To 0x8F, 0x97 To 0x9F, 0xB8 To 0xB9, 0xC1 To 0xDA, 0xE0, 0xE8
                ContinueLoop
            Case Else
                If BitAND(DllStructGetData($tState, 1, $i + 1), 0xF0) Then
                    $Key = $i
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
        EndSwitch
    Next
    If $Key <> $Prev Then
        GUICtrlSetData($Label, '0x' & Hex($Key, 2))
        $Prev = $Key
    EndIf
WEnd
```

Comment: Out of curiosity tested your script. It can't detect combinations of keys for me (like ctrl+smth), only a single keypress. So if you are right about hidden alternative combination (which is arguable, but i'm not an expert), script will allow to detect only trivial cases.

Comment: Yes, but it will detect the special function key. If you want to find out what the alternative combination of your G10 or something key is, then I guess this is well documentated or easy to google.

Comment: It looks like the MadCatz Keyboard doesnt send a known KeyCode. So the script doesnt show that a button is clicked when I press the "special function key"
Is there a way to get the raw data the KeyBoard sends on USB Port to send it manualy to the MadCatz Software?